# Как перенаправиться при выборе пункта в форме

Tags: javascript, django

Как лучше сделать следующее? Пользователь выбирает 2 пункта на форме, если все нормально, то пользователь переходит на урл из action формы, а если пункты не совместимы как в этом случае остаться в этом урле?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно Вас понял, Вы хотите отменить отправку формы на сервер, если какие-то её пункты противоречат друг другу.

Вам следует повесить обработчик события `submit` на форму. В колбэке нужно выполнить проверку соответствующих пунктов, и если всё ок -- можно просто выйти из функции. Если всё не ок, то можно, либо вернуть `false`, либо вызвать `e.preventDefault` и форма никуда не уйдёт, и можно будет показать уведомление об ошибке или ещё что-нибудь сделать.

[Вот здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/forms-submit) можно почитать и посмотреть, как конкретно это делается.